# Java and REST POST method - how to transform URL POST request to JSON Body POST Request?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, post

I have class which works completely and sends POST request successfully toward the external system.
paramaters which are sent currently in the class are:

```
username:maxadmin
password:sm
DESCRIPTION: REST API test
```

Now I want to do copy paste of this class and transform it in that way so I could POST request using the JSON body but I am not sure how to do it.
I saw that I should probably have `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Can someone please transform my code in order to POST REQUEST using JSON body for parameters sending instead of URL?
This is my 'URL' working class (you will see username/password are in URL while parameters are send in array I have currently only one attribute DESCRIPTION which I am sending)

```
package com.getAsset;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.json.*;

public class GETAssetsPOST {


public static String httpPost(String urlStr, String[] paramName,
        String[] paramVal) throws Exception {

          URL url = new URL(urlStr);
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          conn.setUseCaches(false);
          conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);                          
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();                          
          Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");

          for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
            writer.write(paramName[i]);
            writer.write("=");
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8"));
            writer.write("&");
          }
          writer.close();
          out.close();                    

          if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
          }

          // Buffer the result into a string
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

          String line;
         while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line);
          }
         rd.close();
                      conn.disconnect();
          return sb.toString();
        }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
String[] attr = new String[1];
String[] value = new String[1];
attr[0] = "DESCRIPTION";
value[0] = "REST API test";
String description = httpPost("http://192.168.150.18/maxrest/rest/os/mxasset/123?_lid=maxadmin&_lpwd=sm",attr,value);
System.out.println("\n"+description);

}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: off topic, but hard coded credentials are a no-no. probably should just use a simple custom jndi resource

Comment: Hi Jason. Do you think it is complicated to transform this into the JSON structure for Request sending?

Comment: i've never done it. I always use conversions between JSON and lists, and just convert them to whatever state i'd like them on the other end.

Comment: Can you give me an example how will my code look in that case?

Comment: unfortunately i can not right now, i was just browsing for a moment while my production server started. I may be able to come back later and help out

Comment: ok, thank you anyway..